# Javascript list available connections

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to list all available connections my raspberry pi can find in a dropdown list, with the intention to connect to the one selected.

I found a library which should fit my needs however i just can't wrap my head around it. [node-wireless](https://github.com/tlhunter/node-wireless)

Here is the html code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/wifilist.js"></script>
<label for="inputlg">WiFi Connections</label>
<select>
    <option value="list_wifi()"></option>
</select>
```

and my javascript file

```
var wireless = new Wireless({
    iface: 'wlan0',
    updateFrequency: 10, // Optional, seconds to scan for networks
    connectionSpyFrequency: 2, // Optional, seconds to scan if connected
    vanishThreshold: 2 // Optional, how many scans before network considered gone
});




function list_wifi() {
    wireless.enable(function(err) {
        wireless.start();
        console.log(wireless.start());
    });
}
```

screenshot of the app:
[interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vCYq.png)

Comment: That library is designed to be used with Node and probably relies upon system APIs that won't be present in the browser. If you want to display the results in the browser, then you'll need a Node server running and broadcasting the networks, then speak to it with XHR or WebSockets from a client side web app like this.

Answer (score 3):

Connecting your Raspberry to a Wifi network can't be done from the browser, since the browser doesn't have access to such information. Even though it was possible your implementation would still not make much sense, because if you would open that webpage not locally from your Pi's browser but from another PC, it wouldn't show the connection of the Pi but those of that PC.
You need to build a server (e.g. in Node.js in order to use that library), that fetches a list of connetions, prints them to a webpage and handles HTTP requests from the webpage to establish the connection. So basically you will need both a small backend and a frontend.

Comment: I might have not been specific enough. There is a webserver installed on the pi (the pi controls a robot with an interface). so basicly connecting to the pi goes through an ethernet connection (static) and then i wan't to connect the pi in the interface to a wifi connection to recieve web requests from IFTTT.